# Why is transforming a conditional write to an unconditional write not a thread safe optimization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, thread-safety

In a talk about concurrency and the C++11 memory model Herb Sutter gives examples of illegal optimizations.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2

From the slide at minute 17:

```
void f(vector<widget>& v) {
    if(v.length()>0) xMutex.lock();
    for(int i = 0; i < v.length(); ++i)
        ++x;                                  // write is conditional
    if(v.length()>0) xMutex.unlock();
}
```

"A very likely (if deeply flawed) transformation of the central loop:"

```
r1 = x;
for(int i = 0; i < v.length(); ++i)
    ++r1;                                     // oops: write is not conditional
x = r1;
```

He explains, "...this write is not conditional, it will happen on every execution even if doOptionalWork is false, which will inject a write that is not protected by the mutex lock, that injects a race..."

Why does he say the invented write is not protected by the mutex lock? I understood the full transformation being described as the following.

```
// "optimized" version 1
void f(vector<widget>& v) {
    if(v.length() > 0) xMutex.lock()
    r1 = x;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.length(); ++i)
        ++r1;
    x = r1;
    if(v.length() > 0) xMutex.unlock();
}
```

But it could also be this.

```
// "optimized" version 2
void f(vector<widget>& v) {
    if(v.length() > 0) xMutex.lock()
    r1 = x;
    for(int i = 0; i < v.length(); ++i)
        ++r1;
    if(v.length() > 0) xMutex.unlock();
    x = r1;
}
```

Clearly version 2 isn't thread safe but I'm not sure about version 1. Is version 1 thread safe? What if there are no other lines that write to x in play?

Just now I began typing "Either v.length() is 0 or it isn't..." and realized that even tautologies fail me in a multithreaded world. I don't know where I can begin reasoning about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mutex is only used if there is something inside of the vector. Running this method concurrently on two empty vectors results in a data race because we don't lock at all, yet we write to x.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine there is another thread executing the following code:

```
xMutex.lock()
++x;
xMutex.unlock();
```

If the above code is executed at the same time as the (transformed) function `f` with an empty vector, then the increment to `x` may get lost, although that's impossible on the source code level.

Answer (score 0):

The `mutex. lock()` function call is what locks the mutex.  The mutex is a mutually exclusive lock that allows one and only one caller to call `lock()` and return. Subsequebt callers will block,  waiting fir the original caller to call `unlock()`.

It is 'mutually exclusive'  in that only one thread is allowed to get the lock.

That is the definition of a mutex.

in the code you posted,  the second block does not wrap the increment loop with the `lock()` and `unlock()`  calls.

This means that two threads that call functions that change the variable modified within the loop will step on each other.  One may write the variable immediately before (or after)  another loop reads the variable.  The code expects the variable to be consistent withi  the function,  so the behavior of the function will be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this I put together a demo to demonstrate the race.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

// we have very simple widgets
typedef int widget;

// x and its mutex are shared by the threads
static int x = 0;
std::mutex xMutex;

static std::chrono::milliseconds central_loop_dur(10);
static std::chrono::milliseconds before_central_loop(0);

void f(std::vector<widget>& v) {

    // The first thread acquires the lock.
    // The second thread has an empty vector so passes through before the lock is released.
    if(v.size() > 0) xMutex.lock();
    // The first thread will take about 50ms to write to x.
    // The second thread reads x nearly concurrently with the first thread. Both see 0.
    int r = x;

    // The first thread passes through here.
    // The second thread snoozes.
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(before_central_loop);
    before_central_loop = std::chrono::milliseconds(200);

    for(auto i : v) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(central_loop_dur);
        ++r;
    }
    // At 50ms, the first thread writes to x.
    // At 200ms, the second thread obliviously writes a previous value of x back to x.
    x = r;
    if(v.size() > 0) xMutex.unlock();
}

void thread_main(size_t vec_size) {
    std::vector<widget> v(vec_size);
    f(v);
}

int main() {
    std::thread t1(thread_main, 5);
    std::thread t2(thread_main, 0);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << "The value of x = " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Without the sleep instructions, if everything occurred in order the result would be x = 5. Instead, the program will (with high probability) print x = 0, even though thread 1 increments x 5 times!